# Probability of an event occurring two out of three times

Tags: probability, statistics

The probability of an event 'W' is 0.324. What is the probability that of three independent trials, the event W will occur twice?

Why is it not correct to simply say P(W) x P(W) x P(Wcomplement)?

Is this a matter of conditional probability?

Comment: [The binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) can be considered useful here and helps with the generalization of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$W\text{ exactly twice}=(W_1\cap W_2\cap W_3^{\complement})\cup(W_1\cap W_2^{\complement}\cap W_3)\cup(W_1^{\complement}\cap W_2\cap W_3)$$
so a union of $3$ mutually exclusive events.